# I am unable to change the value of my Property

Tags: vb.net

I have the following private attribute.

```
    Private m_blnEnExecution As Boolean
```

And I have the following property.

```
    Public Property EnExecution As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_blnEnExecution
        End Get
        Set
            m_blnEnExecution = EnExecution
        End Set
    End Property
```

Then i tried to change its value in the following method

```
    Public Sub Executer()
        EnExecution = True
    End Sub
```

But when i use the debugger I realized that the value of EnExecution does not change.
What am i doing wrong. I am new in visual basic. Any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/property-vbnet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your setter is incorrect:

```
Set
    m_blnEnExecution = EnExecution
End Set
```

This is setting the value of `m_blnEnExecution` to the *current value* of the property `EnExecution`, which itself is the value of `m_blnEnExecution`.  So this setter will never change the backing value.

Instead, set the backing value to the passed value:

```
Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
    m_blnEnExecution = Value
End Set
```